# Running bcl2fastq on Windows

Tags: bioinformatics

We're looking for a way to run someone with experience with ILMN's NextSeq platform. We're currently trying to convert native bcl files to fastq, but the platform doesn't provide that option by default.

ILMN offers this through the BaseSpace community website/appstore, but this is problematic for us b/c running bcl2fastq through BS doesn't allow us to specify any parameters.

There's a converter tool ILMN offers through their website, which runs on Linux. This is problematic for us, too, as we're essentially a highly regulated (think FDA-level, 21CFR.11 and all those things) Windows environment, so "just" putting a Linux box on-prem is not as simple as it sounds.

So we looked into running bcl2fastq through a VirtualBox VM on top of Windows, but that was rather disappointing; it takes roughly 2 days to run bcl2fastq on a VM, versus under one hour on a "native" Linux setup.

I don't think we've exhausted all of our options yet though to get bcl2fastq to work *somehow* in a Windows environment. Amongst others, the source code of bcl2fastq is actually publicly available, so perhaps we could re-compile the whole thing for a Windows architecture as well.

Comment: did you ask the illumina support ? otherwise ask : http://biostars.org or https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I use a linux VM in Windows 10 for computationally demanding bioinformatics tasks and don't experience the drastic comparative slowness you describe (2d vs 1h). Did you give your VM access to all/most of your CPUs? If you did I would still suspect some other VBox setting(s) could be optimized (eg., more RAM). If it takes 1 hour in Windows it should take only moderately longer in the VM (1.2-1.5 hours tops) if given sufficient resources.